# Python Gchartwrapper using markers from variables

Tags: python, google-visualization

I'm working on a quick python script doing some aggregations from a .csv file, then creating a verticle bar chart for the values. I wanted to know how is it possible to use markers to display the values that contain the data....
ex.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time                     # Imports system time module to time your script
import os
import sys
import math
from GChartWrapper import *

import csv

def stacked_vertical():
        G = VerticalBarGroup([[port5Q],[port6Q],[port5H],[port6H],[port5B],[port6B]], encoding='text' )
        G.color('4d89f9')
        G.size(600,200)
        G.title( 'HFS Port Summary','black',20 )
#       G.marker('N*c1*','black',0,-1,11)     -- having the issue here..
        G.save('bar-vertical-stacked')
        print G
```

Basically i would like the values of port5Q/6Q etc to appear above thier bar graph.

Thanks in advance...